# How much time it takes to create process from process

Tags: linux, exec, fork

I am trying to create a new process from an existing process.

like that parentMain process creates childMain process.

my goal is:
1) Both process will continue running (means no one should wait for another to finish)
2) The creator - parentMain process, should send a message to the created process - childMain process.

I do not know when the new childMain process is actually ready. I can not use the wait function as I understood it waits until 
the child process should end, but my aim is it will continue to run.

After little googling I am using the fork & exec family functions as follows:

```
void parentMain::CreateAndSend()
{
    createNewProcess();
    sendMessage();
}

void parentMain::createNewProcess()
{
    char* param1[10] = "param1";
    // Create new process.
    cpid = fork();

    if (cpid >= 0) // fork() succeeded.
    {
        if (cpid == 0) // 0 for child process.
        {
            execl("/home/kon/childMain", "/home/kon/childMain", param1, (char*)0);
        }
        else /* parent process */
        {
            printf("Parent process, parent PID=%d child PID=%d, getpid(), cpid);
        }
    }
    else // fork() failed.
    {
        printf("Failure");
    }
}

void parentMain::sendMessage()
{

    Y = 50; // milliseconds.
    nanosleep(Y);
    ?? isChildReady ??
    sendChildMessage();

}
```

Now, sometimes sendMessage() fails!
if I am using a sleep(X) it succeeded. (in seconds)
but I want to reduce the time as much as I can.
How much time it takes to a process to be created?
is there any function that says "child is ready"?
How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Show the code for `sendChildMessage()`. By the time `createNewProcess()` returns, assuming `fork(2)` was successful, you will have 2 processes - although it's not deterministic if the child has been given CPU time yet. In any case, if `sendChildMessage()` is reasonably well implemented, it should work.

Comment: Using `sleep` for this purpose is is bad practice in general. If you want to guarantee deterministic behaviour then implement explicit synchronisation between the parent and the child. Consider using [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) for example.

Comment: Thanks. pipe is a better way. Just not to trust on the sleep.